# Display a loading icon until the page loads completely AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, load, ready

I am trying to show a preloader until that all website content load but i cant get it.

Any of this options works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //content load });

$(window).load(function() { //content load });
```

I want some method with AngularJS for quit the preloader when all the images and videos are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your main controller or the controller of your view,
Make sure to wrap your view content around the `ng-view` directive

```
<div ng-view ></div>
```

You can use the above directive as a class or an element as well.

> $viewContentLoaded :
>   Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
  //Here you can hide your pre-loader
});
```

This event is fired after your view is reloaded.